# Ограничение JavaScript на вычисление факториала

Tags: javascript, факториал

Давно интересует, чем ограничено вычисление факториала, на каком именно уровне: на уровне возможностей процессоров или интерпретатора JS, или на каком-то другом? Дело в том, что максимальное число, факториал которого можно вычислить стандартными средствами на JS, - число 170. Все числа с большим значением приводят к результату Infinity. Может, кто-нибудь знает, с чем это связано?

```js
  function factorial(n) {
     if(n == 0 || n == 1) {
      var fact = 1;
     } else {
      var fact = parseInt(n);
      for(var i = 1; i < n; i++) {
       fact *= i;
      }
     }
     return fact;
    }
    
    console.log(factorial(170),'\n----------------------');
    console.log(factorial(171));
```

Comment: Максимальное целое число, которое можно безопасно использовать в JavaScript это 2^53 - 1. Дальше будет потеря точности. Представь, что х = 9007199254740992. Тогда x == x+1 вернёт true! Это и есть потеря точности

Comment: @MishaSaidov можете оформить как ответ.

Comment: @MishaSaidov, но 2^53 - 1 меньше, чем факториал 170, т.е., JS может вычислить это значение, а вот большее нет. К тому же, максимальное числовое значение в JS это значение Number.MAX_VALUE 2^1023.999~
Вопрос в том, чем ограничено число Number.MAX_VALUE

Comment: Стандартом IEEE 754

Comment: Справедливости ради, всё что больше 2^53 вычисляется неточно

Comment: @Romanzhivo, кроме MAX_VALUE, есть еще `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`

Comment: @AlexeyTen, то есть, правильно ли понимаю, что это ограничение искусственное и установленное стандартом, и, теоретически, вычисления могут происходить с большей точностью?
И второй вопрос: стандарт в данном случае реализован на уровне процессоров или компилятора/интерпретатора JavaScript?

Comment: Так написано в стандарте https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-terms-and-definitions-number-value. В питоне, например, можно вычислить факториал любого числа вопрос только во времени и количестве памяти. В последней версии Хрома добавили тип BigInt в котором тоже можно представить произвольное целое число

Comment: @AlexeyTen, понятно, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Мы можем примерно установить границу, где js возвращает бесконечность как результат вычисления:

```js
function factorial(n) {
  if (n == 0 || n == 1) {
    var fact = 1;
  } else {
    var fact = parseInt(n);
    for (var i = 1; i < n; i++) {
      fact *= i;
    }
  }
  return fact;
}

console.log(factorial(170), '\n----------------------');
console.log(Number.MAX_VALUE);
console.log(factorial(171), '\n----------------------');
console.log(Number.MAX_VALUE * 1.000000000000001);
console.log(Number.MAX_VALUE * 1.0000000000000001);
```